# How do I make GDM run ~/.xsession?

Tags: 20.04, gdm, session

I need to run my own session script without changing any system files. In older Ubuntu versions I was able to create a `~/.xsession` script in my home directory containing all session initialization commands and, after selecting "Default Session Script" (or something similar) in the login screen and logging, the session script would run just as expected. I tried this in Ubuntu 20.04 but I couldn't.

Is there a way to make GDM3 call my personal session script?